# extract data with regular expressions, and count them in python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7, count, expression

I need to extract the word 'Author' from a text using regular expressions, and them counting them. This is part of my code:

```
counts=0
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip()
    counts=counts+1
    x=re.findall('(^Author)', line)  
    if len(myword)> 0: print  counts,x
print  counts, "lines that matches Author"
```

I can open the file, and find the word, and get the position with no problems but I don't manage to get how to count them. Could someone help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why regex? https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Because I want to learn how to master regex.

Comment: use another variable `totals = 0` (near `count = 0` line). Then, in your loop, put `total += len(x)`